# How to Use round function with Isblank function in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the round function with the isblank function but when I copy the formula down, I get #value! if there is no value; however if I use only the isblank function then there is no error. my code is below thanks!

```
=ROUND(IF(ISBLANK(D15),"",'Sheet2'!L25+'Sheet2'!P25+'Sheet2'!O25+AK15+AL15),0)
```

Comment: `ISBLANK` does not detect `zero-length` strings so there is a chance that `ROUND` will error out. I suggest you replace `ISBLANK(D15)` with `LEN(D15)=0` or simply `D15=""`.

Comment: @L42 Why don't you post that as an answer. Aren't we all supposed to avoid answering questions in comments?

Comment: @teylyn A.S.H got it covered :). Btw, I didn't post as answer since I'm not certain on the data the OP is working on. So I just put it on comment since there is a possibility that my assumptions are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that you followed the wrong order of things. Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D15),"",ROUND(Sheet2!L25+Sheet2!P25+Sheet2!O25+AK15+AL15,0))
```

Also the comment of `L42` might be appropriate if the `D15` has a formula; `ISBLANC` does not detect blanks that result from formulas. Same if it actualy has spaces only, etc. For this reason consider replacing `ISBLANK(D15)` with `LEN(Trim(D15))=0`.