# How to Use round function with Isblank function in Excel when the isblank function is looking at a cell that has a formula embeded?

Tags: excel

I am using the isblank and round fuctions at the same time but when I copy the formula down and since T5 Cell has a formula in it , an error will come up #value!. Thanks!

```
=IF(ISBLANK(T5),"",ROUND(T5/12,0))
```

Comment: Did you read **carefully** the answer you got [HERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45023681/4926357). I quote: *"if the D15 has a formula; `ISBLANC` does not detect blanks that result from formulas. Same if it actualy has spaces only, etc. For this reason consider replacing `ISBLANK(D15`) with `LEN(Trim(D15))=0`"*

Comment: It could be that the formula in T5 is returning a text values or text-that-looks-like-a-number. The division operation will fail when dividing text by a number. What are you trying to do? Perhaps get number of years from number of months?

Comment: Welcome back @Jeeped. Hope you had nice vacations :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use round function with Isblank function in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023259/how-to-use-round-function-with-isblank-function-in-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(T5),"",ROUND(T5/12,0)),0)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(T5),"",ROUND(T5/12,0)),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for a non-blank number rather than checking for zero-length strings returned by the formula in T5.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(T5), LEN(T5)), ROUND(T5/12,0), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

consider:

```
=IF(T5="","",ROUND(T5/12,0))
```